# jQuery scroll to specific height then slidedown div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidedown

Ok, so I've tried looking at everything on here and many people have suggested adding a width or a height or even using jquery css to hide elements, but nothing is working for me.

I am trying to have 3 elements slideDown when the user scrolls to a specific section of the page. The problem is that the 3 elements flash on the screen for a brief moment then slide down. How do I remove the brief flash?

```js
$('#e1, #e2, #e3').hide();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (height > 400) {
    $('#e1').slideDown(1500);
    $('#e2').slideDown(2000);
    $('#e3').slideDown(2500);
  }
});
```

```css
DIV#customContent DIV.customObj {
  float: left;
  width: 406px;
}

DIV#customContent DIV.customObj DIV {
  display: none;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customContent">
  <div class="customObj">
    <h3>Service</h3>
    <div id="e1">
      <ul>
        <li>business offices</li>
        <li>hotels</li>
        <li>multi-family dwellings</li>
        <li>higher traffic</li>
        <li>passenger and freight</li>
        <li>elevators</li>
        <li>escalators</li>
        <li>wheel chair lifts</li>
        <li>dumbwaiters</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customObj">
    <h3>Modernization</h3>
    <div id="e2">
      <ul>
        <li>business offices</li>
        <li>hotels</li>
        <li>multi-family dwellings</li>
        <li>higher traffic</li>
        <li>passenger and freight</li>
        <li>elevators</li>
        <li>escalators</li>
        <li>wheel chair lifts</li>
        <li>dumbwaiters</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customObj">
    <h3>Lift Solutions</h3>
    <div id="e3">
      <ul>
        <li>business offices</li>
        <li>hotels</li>
        <li>multi-family dwellings</li>
        <li>higher traffic</li>
        <li>passenger and freight</li>
        <li>elevators</li>
        <li>escalators</li>
        <li>wheel chair lifts</li>
        <li>dumbwaiters</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as a snippet?

Comment: Can you please, your code snippet is not working the way it should..

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet to reproduce your problem ?